# Avoiding performance state slowdown

Tags: cuda

When executing my CUDA program, I have noticed that if run twice close after each other then the second execution is much faster (~100µs vs ~300µs). This correlates very well with the current performance state of the CUDA device. When run close after each other the device stays in P2 state, but after some delay it drops to P5 and then to P8, leading to the slower execution time.

[Graph showing execution time vs performance state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSvVx.png)

My question is now, how do I best avoid this decreased performance? Is there a setting that I can use that will prevent the CUDA device from going to P5 and P8? I'd prefer if it is possible to apply this either through the API or from the command line.

I had a look at the throttle reasons and the ones that are in play are NONE, IDLE and UNKNOWN, and they correlate with the performance state, Streaming Multiprocessor clock and memory clock. See following graphs:

[Graphs showing other correlations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9TXZ.png)

It is a little difficult to see in the graphs, but they show that when the system is running at full speed, a throttle reason UNKNOWN is reported. When the SM clock drops from 1417 to 1240 it is not reporting any throttle reasons. When the SM clock then drops to 1012 and below it reports throttle reason IDLE.

My system is running Windows Server 2012 R2 and the CUDA device is a TITAN X (Pascal) with driver version 371.90 running in TCC mode. I am running default clock settings as can be seen here:

```
Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 0000:82:00.0
    Clocks
        Graphics                    : 139 MHz
        SM                          : 139 MHz
        Memory                      : 405 MHz
        Video                       : 544 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : 1417 MHz
        Memory                      : 5005 MHz
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : 1417 MHz
        Memory                      : 5005 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                    : 1911 MHz
        SM                          : 1911 MHz
        Memory                      : 5005 MHz
        Video                       : 1708 MHz
    SM Clock Samples
        Duration                    : 330.48 sec
        Number of Samples           : 100
        Max                         : 1417 MHz
        Min                         : 139 MHz
        Avg                         : 598 MHz
    Memory Clock Samples
        Duration                    : 330.48 sec
        Number of Samples           : 100
        Max                         : 4513 MHz
        Min                         : 405 MHz
        Avg                         : 1493 MHz
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                  : N/A
        Auto Boost Default          : N/A
```

Comment: https://www.microway.com/hpc-tech-tips/nvidia-smi_control-your-gpus/

Comment: I don't see anything in that article that explains how I can avoid throttling the device. I updated my question to add additional details about reported throttling reasons and the device clock settings.

Comment: It specifically discusses how to use nvidia-smi to set the performance state of your GPU from the command line. Isn't that your question?

Comment: I must be missing something because I cannot find anything in that article that describes how to avoid throttling. It describes that TCC mode should be set, which I already have set. It then describes how to query clocks and throttling reasons and explicitly writes that it is not possible to run at max speed all the time due to throttling. The only thing I can see which could potentially affect my case is the -ac parameter to nvidia-smi, but as far as I can tell it does not affect throttling, but only default application clocks.

Please tell which command in nvidia-smi I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find anything in the API, nor in nvidia-smi, that allowed me to keep the performance state in P2, so instead I created an empty kernel that I call at regular intervals (every 10 seconds). This is a hacky approach, but it does keep the performance state in P2.

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to use `nvidia-settings` to change the PowerMizer mode:

```
nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1"
```